# What happens to Completed Games list when a title is updated with new achievements?

Tags: achievements, xbox-network

In Xbox Home we can see all our achievements. There is also a screen called "Completed games" that shows all games that we have max. gamerscore, that is, got all achievements. So far, so good.

So what happens when a completed game earn new achievements? Is it removed from the list of completed games?

Why I am asking this: Happy Wars is listed as a Completed Game in my screen. But recently they launched a title update with some new achievements.

Obviously I don't have those achievements, but it is still listed as a Completed Game. I've not downloaded the title update yet, but what will happen after I do so?

Comment: Good question. If it works like the PS trophies, I'd say the game is automatically listed as "completed" if you get all base achievements (achievements, that weren't added through DLCs), even if you got the DLC. I faintly remember managing such a feat on the Xbox, but my game didn't get listed, so maybe not?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The different part here is that it is not a DLC: it is a title update. This is very uncommon. The "base game" changed and added new achievements. If you download the game now, you get it with all achievements (old and new together).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you download the title update, the game will no longer be listed as completed. The only reason it is still listed that way on your console is because it isn't aware that there are additional achievements.

If you look at your profile on Xbox.com, the entry for Happy Wars will not show 100% achievements for your gamertag.

Comment: That's unfair. But it seems to be right. :(

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz Yeah, it's annoying for completionists everywhere. :(